# Azure-cognitive-services giving "404 resource not found"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have subscribed "Azure Cognitive Services" and I tried to convert language translation from English to Danish. I have made a post request with **Postman** but every time I received the below error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "404",
        "message": "Resource not found"
    }
}
```

My endpoint what I can see in Azure dashboard is
**https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=da**

and I have posted both **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** and **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region** keys in the header section.

Why am I getting 404 error? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For text translator API V3.0, you can find the base URL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#base-urls)

If you are in Europe , you can try this endpoint :

```
api-eur.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com
```

[image]

Comment: Along with the URL in your answer, I have to add both Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key="..." and Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region="uksouth" in the request header to get the result.

Comment: @Simant Glad to know that your issue has been solved , pls mark me if my suggestions are helpful , thanks !